# TinyMCE editor setContent responds with can't read null property

Tags: php, tinymce

I was trying to add content to the TinyMCE textarea from MySQL. I used `setContent(content)`, but the textarea didn't get filled with content on page refresh, and I got this error message below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of null

```
<script src="__PUBLIC__/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script> tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',plugins:'code',content_css:"__PUBLIC__/custom_content.css"});
tinymce.get('textarea').setContent(content....);
</script>
<script src="__PUBLIC__/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="content" placeholder="content..." rows="30"></textarea>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I moved the question to the top so folks don't have to search for it and turned the error message into a quote. Is `.setContent(content....);` really what you have in your code or was that intended as a placeholder for your actual php code to pull from mysql?

Comment: @JasonAller it is intended as a placeholder and I has successfully retrieved data from local storage and printed into this .setContent() function.

Comment: A shorter version using init section: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31625136/5719185

Answer (score 2):

5 years late but I stumbled onto this thread myself trying to figure this one out just now.

For anybody else stumbling here, it turns out .get() has to be an ID, without the hashtag. So .get('textarea') looks for a textarea that has an id="textarea" attribute, not JUST a textarea.

For me, the following works:

```
tinymce.get('fldDescription').setContent("<p>test</p>");
```

But the following does not:

```
tinymce.get('#fldDescription').setContent("<p>test</p>");
```

This is TinyMCE 5.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `tinymce.*` functions too early - when the element doesn't even exist in the DOM. Place the `<script>` to below the `<textarea>` and try again.

Alternatively, wrap your `tinymce.*` calls like this (also note the jQuery script placement):

```
<script src="__PUBLIC__/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="__PUBLIC__/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    plugins:'code',
    content_css:"__PUBLIC__/custom_content.css"
  });
  tinymce.get('textarea').setContent(content....);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Strange as it is,I still don't know why it doesn't work,I've tested to add the code wherever it is,and,not working,it's not the DOM hasn't been created kind of thing. tinymce.get('textarea') always return NULL for me,and I have to use .html() alternatively.