# Tinymce 4.2.0 got Cannot read property 'setContent' of null

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I got Cannot read property 'setContent' of null, when i want to using setContent function. Intended for set value in text editor generated by Tinymce library. Is am wrong to implemented it?Below is my snippet code:

```
<textarea name="content"></textarea>      
<script src="assets/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea'
  });          
  tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('custom');
</script>
```

Does anyone knows about this problem?
Thanks! any effort would be appreciated

Answer (score 16):

You have to wait until the editor is initialized:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector:'textarea',
  init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
    editor.setContent('custom');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Real late to the party, but tinyMCE.init also has *setup* configuration option which allows to add any event handlers to the specific editor being initialised:

```
tinymce.init({
        setup: editor => {
            editor.on('init', () => {
                editor.setContent('custom');
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: After spending a lot of time on this extremely annoying little problem and trying out many different proposed solutions, yours was the only solution that worked for me. Thx! I cannot believe that the authors of tinymce have coded their otherwise excellent application in such a way that this error occurs unless the content is set upon initialization. It makes zero sense, has zero utility and is undoubtedly just a massive time-waster for many devs out there...

Answer (score 0):

There is other turn around for your solution:

Call setContent within $( window ).load(function(){}) but you have initialize jquery first.

Modified code will look like below:

```
<textarea name="content"></textarea>      
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea'
  }); 
$( window ).load(function(){         
  tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('custom');
});
</script>
```