# Need help understanding how to use setContent() function in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am passing text from page 1 to page 2 using LocalStorage. Page2 textarea uses TinyMCE editor. I found this function on the Tiny site which I think is designed for that purpose. However I am new to Javascript and can't make it work. Any help ?

[TinyMCE page and function:](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

My Html:

```
<div class=" form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><label for="work">Scope of Work:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10"><textarea id="wo_scope" class="form-control tinymce " rows="5" placeholder="Required / Maximum 500 characters" name="work" cols="50"></textarea></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you having trouble with? "Teach me javascript" is too broad for SO.

Comment: I do not specifically understand how to use the prototype at the type at the top of the page: 

public function setContent(content:String, args:Object):String  Specifically what what do I do with the ":String" at the end of the function?

Comment: The `:String` at the end just tells you that this function returns a string. See the "Returns" section at the end of the doc page.

Comment: @JasonP Great. When I run the following:  function setfunction() {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('some text');
            }  I get nothing in the editor. So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @JasonP What's more, I have 3 text areas with Tiny in them. So need to uniquely ID each one of them. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load content into TinyMCE as a page loads you can use the `setContent` function to do that ... but you need to make sure that TinyMCE is initialized before you try to use `setContent`.

The best way to do that is to put the code to load the content into the configuration object for TinyMCE.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
        var dataFromLS = <code to get the HTML from local storage>;
        this.setContent(dataFromLS);
    });
  }
  ... 
});
```

The basic way to use `setContent()` is just to pass the HTML to is as the only parameter of the method.  If you have the data in local storage just grab that first into a JS variable and then do something like this:

```
var dataFromLS = <code to get the HTML from local storage>;
tinymce.get('wo_scope').setContent(dataFromLS);
```

Note that in the init example I provided above you can refer to the editor instance as `this`.  You can also get it based on the ID of the`<textarea>` that you replace with TinyMCE.  A more complete (correct) example could do something like this:

```
tinymce.get('wo_scope').setContent(datafromLS);
```

The `setContent()` method works on a specific instance of TinyMCE so you need to have one before you can call `setContent()`.  My examples above show two ways to get that instance `get()` and in the init using `this`.

*Note:  In one of your comments above you use `tinymce.activeEditor` - that only works if you have clicked into a TinyMCE editor instance - that makes it the "active" editor.  If you are doing this on page load you almost certainly don't yet have an active editor.*

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can not make your code work. I just nothing, or I get an error saying that it can not read the property of 'get'. I have placed it into the header as instructed within the user guide.   I have also tried placing it at the bottom of the page. Perhaps it is relevant that I have 3 different text areas all with different id's . I found on Stackoverflow some instructions give did give me an out put, but the output was applied to all the textareas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085242/tinymce-4-2-0-got-cannot-read-property-setcontent-of-null

Comment: I keep getting the error message: **"Cannot read property 'setContent' of null"**  Here is the code I am using: `tinymce.init({
             selector:'textarea'
           });
            var mydata = '<span>hello from tiny</span> html'
            tinymce.get('wo_scope').setContent(mydata);`

Comment: This would mean that `tinymce.get('wo_scope')` is failing.  I suspect you are calling `get()` before the editor is fully initialized ... see my note above about using the on `init` option in the configuration for TinyMCE.  I bet if you open the JavaScript console in the browser after the editor is loaded your `setContent()` call would work ... if it does its just a timing issue.

Comment: It's Working ! Many thanks !! I did this:             `$('#wo_scope').html('<span>hello from scope</span>');
               tinymce.init({
                selector:'textarea'
            });`


Question: what if I want to limit Tiny to specific text areas ie not my whol site  ?

Comment: The `selector` part of your configuration allows you to target certain elements based on CSS rules:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#selector